# Why my DAG doesnt work and marked succesfully?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, airflow

i wrote a DAG, but when i trigger it, nothing happens, but in UI i can see, that it ended succesfully. Here is the code

```
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
import airflow
import requests
import requests.exceptions as requests_exceptions
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator




with DAG(
    dag_id='test',
    start_date=datetime.today(),
    schedule_interval=None
) as dag:



    def _select():
        engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:123456@localhost:5433/main_base")
        try:
            with engine.connect() as conn:
                statement = conn.execute(text(
                    '''
                    INSERT INTO public.main("id", "name")
                    VALUES (5, "'med'");
                    '''
                ))
                conn.commit()
                return True
        except:
            return False


    insert_data = PythonOperator(
        task_id='insert_data',
        python_callable=_select,
        dag=dag,
    )





    insert_data
```

I checked postgres connection, table, etc, all is ok, when i used this func in IDE it worked

Answer (score 0):

The `_select` function will never fail due to the `try-except` block. As a result, your task succeeds. However, because you're returning `False` in the case of an error from `_select`, you may see False in Airflow XCom, as shown below.
[image]

If you want to fail your task in case of error either remove `try-except` or raise an error in case of error.